# Scraping: accept button privacy

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors

I need some help closing the button of privacy while I'm doing scraping for an academic project. I am scraping from [www.kayak.it](http://www.kayak.it).
In this moment I obtain an error when I try to click the button and close privacy. Anyway without that part my following code doesn't work and I obtain an empty dictionary.
My code is the following. Can you help me please? Thank you :)

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin

import sys
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
import pandas
import json
import pprint

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36")

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

wd.get("https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-anywhere/20210801,20210801") 

time.sleep(3)

cookie_banner = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector("button")
if len(cookie_banner) > 0:
   print('Privacy found')
cookie_banner[0].click()

import pprint 
detail_travels = [] 
for travel in list_travels: 
   url = travel.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")[0].get_attribute("href")
   destination = "" 
   country = ""
   travel_id = ""
   if(len(travel.find_elements_by_css_selector(".City__Name")) > 0): 
     destination = travel.find_elements_by_css_selector(".City__Name")[0].text 
   if(len(travel.find_elements_by_css_selector(".Country__Name")) > 0):
     country = travel.find_elements_by_css_selector(".Country__Name")[0].text
   travel_id = url

   detail_travels.append({'url': url,
                        'destination': destination,
                        'country': country,
                        'travel_id': travel_id})

len(detail_travels)
pprint.pprint(detail_travels[0:2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap that code inside `try and except` and then a **create a list of button** with `id` **accept** - (if `length is >0` then it means that element is visible),

see below for more details :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("https://www.kayak.it/explore/MIL-anywhere/20210801,20210801")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
try:
    if(len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id$='accept']"))) > 0:
        print("button that contains id accept, is seen in the UI")
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[id$='accept']"))).click()
    else:
        print("button is not seen")
except:
    print("something went wrong")
    pass
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you, It's working well!!! Could you please help me also with the part of url? In the code I've written 'url = travel.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")[0].get_attribute("href")', but the code gives me the error "list index out of range". Thank you again!

Comment: looks like that's a different issue, Could you create a new ticket for that. I am pretty much sure that Community and I would like to help you on that as well. Now since the above answer, solve your issue, I would appreciate if , you could  accept and upvote (click on upvote button) this answer so that it will be available in green color for future readers. In case if you would like to accept this answer, please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this. –